# Fluid width single line textarea

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a div with a fluid-width textarea inside it. The width of the div should be at least 3em, at most 12em, and otherwise the exact same width as the textarea. I've got this working. [See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8ny99).

When the textarea fills up the div, it creates a line break rather than overflowing to the left, which is the effect I'm going for. Any ideas how to achieve this?

Edit: This code is based on [A List Apart's article on Expanding Text Areas](http://alistapart.com/article/expanding-text-areas-made-elegant).

**html**

```
<div><pre><span></span><br></pre>
  <textarea autofocus placeholder='Note'></textarea>
</div>
```

**css**

```
div {
    border: 1px solid grey;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
/*     overflow: hidden; */
    height: 1.3rem;
    min-width: 3rem;
    max-width: 12rem;
}
textarea {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    resize: none;
    background: rgba(0,0,255,.5);
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
textarea, pre {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
/*     visibility: hidden; */
}
pre {
    border: 1px solid pink;
    position: relative;
    max-width: 100%;
}
* {
    font: 1rem arial;
}
```

**js**

```
var textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');
var span = document.querySelector('span');
textarea.addEventListener('input', function() {
  span.textContent = textarea.value;
});
```

Comment: If it's only one line tall, why not use an input box?

Comment: Are you copying the text to the input box again somehow?  Reduce your CSS to a bare minimum in a separate JSFiddle and try it then... you might see what is happening better.

Comment: @DrLivingston The textbox is sometimes used for multi-line input and I was hoping to switch between multi-line and single-line modes simply by changing CSS classes.

Comment: oh I see... that does make things more complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your CSS use:

```
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
```

Edit this is deprecated:
Can you set `wrap="off"` as an attribute on the `textarea`?

edit: to say overflow: hidden; (per comment below) original: overflow: auto;

Comment: How could I have overlooked that? Thank you. It should be `overflow: hidden`. Please update the answer and I'll accept it. See the [updated fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/8ny99/2/).

Comment: In the question I did ask for overflow to the left, but I didn't intend for it to be visible. Sorry for the confusion.